# Error: Failed to collect page data from /blog/[id]

Tags: node.js, next.js, fetch

```js
const Details = ({ userData }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{userData?.header}</h1>
    </Layout>
   )
}

export default Details

 
export const getStaticPaths = async () =>{
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/blogs`);
  const blogs = await res.json();
  const ids = blogs.map((blog) => blog.id);
  const paths = ids.map((id)=> ({params:{id: id.toString()}}));

  return{
    paths,
    fallback:false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) =>{
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/blogs/${context.params.id}`);
  const userData = await res.json();

  return{
    props:{
      data,
      userData,
    }
  }
}
```

While `npm run build` my Next.js project, I am getting such an error in the console:

```
Error: Failed to collect page data from /blog/[id]
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Before asking question, it may be beneficial to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the various pages in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: configuring similar errors, I imported my own data.js file as import {data}. but ı didn't fix my mistake. help me please.

Comment: This is during build time right?

Comment: Can this help you: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14505#discussioncomment-29715

Comment: unfortunately i saw this and tried it but nothing changed.

Comment: If you want I can share my more detailed codes.

Comment: Can you share your `/blog/[id]` page?

Comment: Please share code instead of image.

Comment: Did I show it more clearly? is there any other result needed?

Comment: Is your api the `nextjs` api? or an independant `express` api? By the way thanks for the effort of sharing code :)

Comment: api in my own api data.js like this
export const data = [ {

Comment: what is this endpoint: `http://localhost:3000/api/blogs` ? And can you share an exemple of `data` ?

Comment: Whatever you want, I can answer immediately. as long as we solve it. I'm stuck because I'm a junior frontend developer.

Comment: Did the answer helped? I can add ore details if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of you are not fetching anything from any Api, you don't need to fetch anything remotly. That's why you are getting an ECONNREFUSED error.

### Update

I've found two errors in your `/blog/*` folder:

- Add `- 1` in line 106 of `/blog/[id].js` (See bellow)
- Remove lines 131 and 132 of `/blog/index.js`

**/blog/[id].js**

```js
import { data } from "../../data.js";

const Details = ({ userData }) => {
  return <Layout>{/* ... */}</Layout>;
};

export default Details;

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const ids = data.map(({ id }) => id);
  const paths = ids.map((id) => ({ params: { id: id.toString() } }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  // You where trying here to get posts by id:
  // 1, 2, 3, 4
  // But what you really want is to get array indexes:
  // 0, 1, 2, 3
  // that's why we are adding - 1
  const userData = data[context.params.id - 1]; // <----- add - 1

  return {
    props: {
      data,
      userData,
    },
  };
};
```

**/blog/index.js**

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  // ----- remove the fetch -----

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you please look at the photo I added last time, it gives these errors while downloading your codes and now while building.

Comment: If you solve it, don't get me wrong, but I want to hug you, I've been dealing with this for 3 days. :)      picture at the top.

Comment: Did something change with my code?

Comment: no.I did copy paste.

Comment: If you want I can upload githup and send you a link.

Comment: Error: Abort fetching component for route: "/blog/[id]"   => devtools also gives this error.

Comment: Please share a Github. I’ll help you!

Comment: Thank you very much. thanks thanks    https://github.com/emirtetik/Frontmir-Portfolio

Comment: Error: Error serializing `.userData` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/blog/[id]".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.    now i have this problem when i start the project

Comment: I couldn't see the change you made. How do I branch merge the changes you made on github?  thank you so much.

Comment: I have simply edited may answer on stackoverflow. Have a look, you will understand

Comment: If you come to Turkey on vacation, you can definitely contact me and I will help you with everything. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I had a import of a module at the top like `import { pusherServer } from '@/lib/pusher';`. It is asynchronous. I moved the import inside the GET request function it was supposed to be called in, and did const `{ pusherServer } = require('@/lib/pusher');`, which is synchronous and waits for it to load. This fixed it. Locally I had no problem building but when deploying on my VPS I had the error message of "Error: Failed to collect page data for {route}" pop up.

edit: The reason I had a problem deploying on the VPS was because I was using coolify and the option of injecting the secrets during buildtime was turned off. Therefore the asynchronous way of doing "import from @/lib/pusher" was not working. After enabling it I was able to use the import method instead of require(). What require() did was inject the secret during runtime, not buildtime